# Javascript sidebar toggle adding animation (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a sidebar on the left that toggles display none and block.

Here is the css:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

And the javascript function:

```
function elToggle() {
  var s = document.getElementById('sidebar');
  if (s.classList.contains('hide')) {
    s.classList.remove("hide");
    s.classList.add("show");
  } else {
    s.classList.remove("show");
    s.classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

The above works fine but I need a smooth animation (slide in and out) when it hides and shows.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a smooth animation, then you need to alter the css

For example, if you want it to fade in and out,

```
.hide {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

I can't possibly write all the transitions, so it depends on how you want the transition to happen

For it to take up no space

```
.hide {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

For sliding in and out, use this

```
.hide {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transition: left 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 100%;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  transition: left 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Note: To use this, the container should have overflow set to hidden and display relative  */
```

Note: make sure the container holding the elements have a display of relative

Comment: These are all fading effects which don’t go well in a sidebar. I was looking for a slide in and out effect

Comment: Ok, that's also easy. It's all about the css. Give me 5min to update

Comment: It depends on your knowledge of css, you can change it however you want
Also use `left` or  `right` depending on the position of the navbar

Answer (score 1):

You are should use `opacity`. Because not working `display` animation(`transition`).

```
.hide {
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: These are all fading effects which don’t go well in a sidebar. I was looking for a slide in and out effect